# Find words with repeating characters

Tags: regex, perl

Want search every word in a dictionary what has the same character exactly at the second and last positon, and one times somewhere middle.

examples:

```
statement - has the "t" at the second, fourth and last place
severe = has "e" at 2,4,last
abbxb = "b" at 2,3,last
```

wrong

```
abab = "b" only 2 times not 3
abxxxbyyybzzzzb - "b" 4 times, not 3
```

my grep is not working

```
my @ok = grep { /^(.)(.)[^\2]+(\2)[^\2]+(\2)$/ } @wordlist;
```

e.g. the

```
perl -nle 'print if /^(.)(.)[^\2]+(\2)[^\2]+(\2)$/' < /usr/share/dict/words
```

prints for example the

```
zarabanda
```

what is wrong.

What should be the correct regex?

EDIT:

And how to i can capture the enclosed groups? e.g. for the

```
statement - want cantupre: st(a)t(emen)t - for the later use

my $w1 = $1; my w2 = $2; or something like...
```

Comment: `[^\2]` does not do what you think, the characters are literal inside character class brackets.

Comment: Not exactly literal, the `\2` represents a chr(2) a.k.a. Ctrl-B

Comment: Is this right or wrong: `xxxix`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the regex that should work for you:

```
^.(.)(?=(?:.*?\1){2})(?!(?:.*?\1){3}).*?\1$
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/bEMgutE7t5

Comment: This regex is using positive and negative lookaheads. It just means that 2nd character should be followed by exactly 2 similar characters but not 3 or more characters.

Comment: It's an extension of the trick that allows `/foo/ && /bar/` to be written as `/^(?=.*?foo)(?=.*?bar)/`.

Comment: Please, added one sub-question. because don't know to where put the capture `()` for caturing the enclosed strings. Could you help?

Comment: Use `(.*?)\1(.*?)\1` instead of `(?:.*?\1){2}` to capture the strings between the char. Or use my much more straightforward solution :)

Comment: @ikegami thank you - unfortunately i can't accept your answer, the OP already accepted this one. :)

Answer (score 12):

`(?:(?!STRING).)*` is `STRING` as `[^CHAR]*` is to `CHAR`, so what you want is:

```
^.             # Ignore first char
(.)            # Capture second char
(?:(?!\1).)*   # Any number of chars that aren't the second char
\1             # Second char
(?:(?!\1).)*   # Any number of chars that aren't the second char
\1\z           # Second char at the end of the string.
```

So you get:

```
perl -ne'print if /^. (.) (?:(?!\1).)* \1 (?:(?!\1).)* \1$/x' \
   /usr/share/dict/words
```

To capture what's in between, add parens around both `(?:(?!\1).)*`.

```
perl -nle'print "$2:$3" if /^. (.) ((?:(?!\1).)*) \1 ((?:(?!\1).)*) \1\z/x' \
   /usr/share/dict/words
```

Comment: To capture what's in between, add parens around both `(?:(?!\1).)*`. (Updated)

Answer (score 1):

Using lookahead:

```
/^.(.)(?!(?:.*\1){3}).*\1(.*)\1$/
```

Meaning:

```
/^.(.)(?!(?:.*\1){3})  # capture the second character if it is not
                       # repeated more than twice after the 2nd position
.*\1(.*)\1$              # match captured char 2 times the last one at the end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my @ok = grep {/^.(\w)/; /^.$1[^$1]*?$1[^$1]*$1$/ } @wordlist;
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but please get rid of those `{1}` pseudo-quantifiers.  All they're doing is clutter up the regex.